# Is SQL*Plus a free download/use?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Is SQL*Plus free to download and use, or does your organization need to purchase a license. And if it is free to download and use, where would be a safe place from which to download it? I need Oracle version 19c Release 3, although I can get away with Oracle version 11g or higher.

Comment: why are you asking here? ... you should be asking the author

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about licensing are off-topic here.  For details see [Questions about licensing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963) and also [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Legal questions, including questions about copyright or licensing, are off-topic for Stack Overflow. [opensource.se] or [law.se] may be suitable alternatives.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download only SQLPlus via the 'lite' Instant Client offering.

It's called the SQL*Plus Package, look for a file download similar to -

```
instantclient-sqlplus-windows.x64-21.6.0.0.0dbru.zip
```

There's no installer, just unzip and start using.

[image]

[You can find the download for the Instant Client on Windows here.](https://www.oracle.com/cis/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html)

Is it free?

YES.

> Instant Client is free from OTN for anyone to use in a development or
> production environment. However, customers can only call Oracle
> Support if they already have a standard support contract.

If you like a command-line interface, but you're looking for a more modern feel, and powerful features and commands, we also have [SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/database/sqldeveloper/technologies/sqlcl/) - which is again, FREE.

See if you can spot the differences...

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm an Oracle employee, and a product manager on the database tools team.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I'm using SQL*Plus for an Informatica tutorial and it says I need Oracle version 19c Release 3, or at least Oracle version 11g or higher. So, following your link, I've downloaded instantclient basic package version 19.16. Thank you.

Comment: Enjoy your tutorial! Note that most of those will use commands/scripts that will run just fine in SQL Developer as well - which would generally be easier to use than SQLPlus.

Comment: The instant client doesn't have an install or set up component. The instructions I've found on the web for installing it are somewhat involved. I've unzipped the files and put them on the c drive. And I've gone into control panel>advanced system properties>environment variables and entered a variable (not even sure what the variable means/comes from) and a corresponding value (path to the instant client). After that the install instructions lead me to writing some code in notepad and maybe on the command prompt. It's at this point that I'm lost in the weeds.

Comment: Jimbo - you only need to make sure that this in your OS PATH env var (windows gives you a GUI for this by the way) C:\OracleInstantClient\instantclient_19_11 -- or wherever you put yours. That SQLPlus EXE doesn't need this though.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I'm not sure I understand your last comment. I can't find an SQLPlus EXE. Not sure how to actually start the program up. Maybe the lite edition is easier to install? Sorry for the zero knowledge factor here. I'm a novice trying to learn everything at once.

Comment: i gave you the exact file to look for on the download page...you're not telling me anything about what you actually grabbed/downloaded

Comment: I downloaded instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.16.0.0.0dbru.zip. Once I unzip it, I've got a vc14 folder at the top of a list, below that is adrci, followed by 24 files, sym files, applications, application extensions, and jar files. Also included is TNSNAMES.ORA, a text document I added following install instructions I found on the web. At the very bottom of the list is xstreams. I'm not seeing any EXE file listed. Not in the vc14 folder either.

Comment: don't download that, download instantclient-sqlplus-windows.x64-21.6.0.0.0dbru.zip

Comment: Ok, I'll uninstall 19 and install 21.6. Thank you for sticking with me!

Comment: Aside from the network folder at the top, the list of files for 21.6.0.0.0bru look similar to the file list for 19.16. I'm not seeing an EXE file.

Comment: there is only one directory and 6 files in the ~1MB download pkg that my answer is referencing

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing. It may be I need to install Microsoft VIsual Studio 2017 Redistributable before downloading the instant client. I'll work on that. Thank you.

Comment: you downloaded the wrong file/pack